# reference to Component stored in localstorage is undefined on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component `Widget` which takes a reference to a Component class and its properties as props and renders it.

This widget is rendered from a `WidgetList` Component which maps over the list of widgets which it stores in its state, as well as keeps the list updated in `localStorage` so that it can be persistent across reload.

```
class WidgetList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const storedWidgets = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('widgets')) || null;
    this.state = {
      widgets: storedWidgets
    }
  }

  onChange(updatedWidgets) {
    localStorage.setItem('widgets', JSON.stringify(updatedWidgets));
    this.setState({ widgets: updatedWidgets });
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      {widgets.map(widget => (
          <div key={widget.id}>
            <Widget data={widget.data} />
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  }
}


const Widget = (props) => {
  const { component: Component, properties } = props.data;
  console.log(Component, properties)
  return <Component {...properties} />;
};
```

The problem is that when I render this, it works fine but on refresh it fails. And the `console.log` returns `undefined` for `Component` and the correct object for `properties`.

I think the problem is that the component is not getting re-imported, but I don't understand how to get around the issue.

Comment: Can it be because when destructuring, you used lower case for the key `const { component: Component, properties }` ("component" != "Component"), so the var is undefined?

Comment: while destructuring, {component: Component} is way of assigning a different name to the extracted variable...it can be read as `component as Component`.

Comment: Thanks, not a pro in destructuring here, reason why i said "Can it be"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `updatedWidgets` should be an object containing a react component. The problem is that a react component can not be serialised properly using `JSON.stringify` and store in `localStorage`

react component can either be a class or function and neither of them can be used with `JSON.stringify`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Since you can not `JSON.stringify` function or class, string is the only viable option, come up the way to build a mapping between a string and react component, save the string in localStorage and convert back to react component later

Something like

```
const widgeMapping = {
    widget1: function () {
        return <div>widge functional component</div>
    },
    widget2: class extends Component {
        render() {
            return <div>widge class component</div>
        }
    }
}

const localStorageData = JSON.stringify({ component: 'widget', properties: { hello: 'world' } })
const parsedData = JSON.parse(localStorageData)
parsedData.component = widgeMapping(parsedData.component)
```

Comment: So the reason my code fails is because the Component Class I'm passing to it is not serialized (and later parsed) properly? How would I get around this?

Comment: AFAIK dynamic imports are also not allowed in JS so I can't just pass a string and then import it as `import {props.component} from '@components'`.

Comment: @ManavM , try to come up with a string which is able to map to a react component somehow